# Use string as variable name ASP

Tags: asp-classic

Im doing a page in .asp and im having this problem ... I have some variable constants

```
MENU_01="FICHEROS"
MENU_02="OPTIONS"
MENU_03="USERS"
```

etc ... what I need to do its a cicle where I can print each variable value by refering it by string ...

```
Dim i
    For i=1 to CANTMENUS 

    Response.Write "<li>"& MENU_0 & i; & "</li>"

    Next
```

Something like that (obviously that do not work) I know the variable name start in MENU_0 and I want dinamicly add the next value to the variable name (the "i" value)

Its this posible to do ??

thanks for all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact I found a way to do this without a set or array! By using eval() func

```
eval("MENU_"&MENUNUMBER)
```

MENUNUMBER its the iteration variable and the variables with the values I want are MENU_01 MENU_02 MENU_03 etc ... and with eval("MENU_01") I get the value I need!

Thanks for all.

Answer (score 4):

Can be done with `Response.Write "<li>"& Eval("MENU_0" & i) & "</li>"` but using eval is not recommended because of it's not a reliable method. 
I'd suggest the use of dictionary object.

```vb
Set MENU = Server.CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    MENU.Add "01", "FICHEROS"
    MENU.Add "02", "OPTIONS"
    MENU.Add "03", "USERS"

For Each Item In MENU.Items
    Response.Write "<li>" & Item & "</li>"
Next
```

Another option is using arrays.